# How to pause a method for a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sleep

I am making a game, and I am trying to add a gravity effect. This is the code I have so far

```
CGRect Bunny = self.Bunny.frame;
CGRect platform = self.platform.frame;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Bunny, platform)){
}else{

    sleep(1);

    self.Bunny.center = CGPointMake (_Bunny.center.x + -0, _Bunny.center.y + 1.5);

    [self Call];

}
```

And the call function just does this so there is no error

```
-(void)Call{

    [self Gravity];
}
```

But the sleep code does not work. Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong, or another way to do this?

Comment: This is always generally a bad idea. If you're making a game and want gravity then use SpriteKit. It is a game engine and has gravity and physics built in.

Comment: @Fogmeister Where can I download this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
```